# How to use security feature provided in desfire from android?

Tags: android, security, nfc, mifare

I know how to read and write ndef messages from a Mifare DESFire tag, but i'm having difficulty as to understand how to use the command set supported by DESFire when it comes to communicating from Android.

1. I know it has something to do with `transceive(byte[])` function which help in communicating through raw bytes. How do i use it?
2. How do i lock the message with custom key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsoDep.transceive()` is indeed the proper method. You can send ISO7816-4 APDUs (like the ones from the [NFC Forum Type 4 Tag specification](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/)) to the tag or use the DESfire-specific command set to communicate with the tag (see http://www.nxp.com/documents/short_data_sheet/MF3ICDX21_41_81_SDS.pdf for a high-level overview).

Locking a message with a custom key requires the use of the DESFire-specific commands. Details for that are described in the datasheet, which is available upon request from NXP; see http://www.nxp.com/products/identification_and_security/smart_card_ics/mifare_smart_card_ics/mifare_desfire/MF3ICD2101DUD.html

Comment: do you have a code snippet anywhere that i can refer to so figure out how to make use of the security feature of a given card? Be it DESFire or Mifare Plus. Just a general flow of transceive commands which help achieve end goal of securing a sector/application?

Comment: You will need to request an Application Note for that from NXP, I think.